# Create and publish a temporal (time series) viewer that synchronizes multiple layers from QGIS

Tags: qgis, time, spatio-temporal-data

I want to create a time series layer viewer as a URL.  I have 3 layers (more will be added):

1. Points1
2. Points2
3. Lines1

When a user changes the time, all layers will synchronize and show the correct composite time-constrained view.
We have tried Mapbox, Power BI and standard webmap publishing in QGIS.  The issue is they only will allow one layer for temporal viewing. How can I include multiple layers?